# Bukkit eclipse Black Line

Tags: java, bukkit

[image]

Why I get this error? How can i solve this?

NOTE: Craftbukkit = 1.9.4. When i used 1.8.0 i didn't get this error.

Comment: is not an error is a warning because the method *getItemInHand* is deprecated....

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error, is just a warning, indicating you that the  method `getItemInHand` is deprecated, the IDE Eclipse is trying to suggest you not to call that method...

> NOTE: Craftbukkit = 1.9.4. When i used 1.8.0 i didn't get this error.

That is the reason, software evolves fast and many things can change from one version to another... That method was ok in version 1.8... but they decided 
to deprecate it since version 1.9

What can you now?

look in the java doc, normally deprecated methods are documented providing new methods that can do the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

ΦXocę already answered why this is happening, so I'll skip that. Instead I'll try to give a solution to your problem.
There is a new method to access the holdingItem, due to the fact Mojang implemented a main and a second hand. This method can be called like this:

```
p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand()
```

It will return the ItemStack in the player's main hand.

Though in this particular situation we can simply use `e.getItem()` to save some resources (remove the player).

Good luck solving the issue.

Comment: "p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand()" i tried it works